# Databind entered number in textbox to a variable in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, textbox

I have a pop-up window containing a textbox that allows the user to type a number in, then click a button which closes the window. How can I bind what the user enters to a double variable in the code behind?

For example in my pop-up window I have:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ...., ElementName ....}" Margin="3" />

<Button Content="close" Click="Close_Popup" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

I want to bind whatever is entered in that textbox to a variable called "double example;" in the code behind.

Is this the proper way to do it? Or will the variable go back to null when I close out of the window?

```
int anInteger;
anInteger = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
```

Here's my xaml for the pop up window:

```
    x:Name="this"
    Title="Scale"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"
    ResizeMode="NoResize">
 <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBlock Text="Enter the distance between these two points in meters:" Margin="3"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding userInput.get, ElementName=this}" x:Name="scaleText_Box" Margin="3"/>
    <Button Content="Done" Click="closeScale_Window" Width="100" Margin="10"/>
 </StackPanel>
```

Here's my code behind for the popup window:

```
public partial class ScaleInputWindow : Window
{
    public ScaleInputWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public double userInput { get; set; }

    private void closeScale_Window(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = true;
    }
}
```

Here's code from my main window.cs, userInput is a double declared at beginning.

```
ScaleInputWindow scaleInput = new ScaleInputWindow();
if (scaleInput.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    userInput = scaleInput.Input;
}
```

Comment: "{Binding ...., ElementName ....}" is not valid.   Post your actual code.  And int is not a double variable.

Comment: Edited it. And yeah I was just using the int conversion as an example, I know you just replace the .ToInt32 with double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't include the get

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=this, Path=userInput}" x:Name="scaleText_Box" Margin="3"/>
```

And you could also just set the DataContext then no ElementName=this
DataContext is more commone

Comment: Thank you very much. I never used the 'Path' keyword before, but did some research on it after you answered. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

According to your code `anInteger` will be 0 as soon as you close the window

You can Declare a Static Variable in separate class in your project and Access it anywhere in project.

```
 public class Popvalue
 {
    public static int anInteger = 0;
 }
```

And on Your pop-up window assign the value to it.

```
  Popvalue.anInteger = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the [ShowDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to show your pop-up window.

In your pop-window code, create a property containing the value. (You can bind this to your TextBox.Text property)

```
public int anInteger {get; set;}
```

Then when the user closes the window (or clicks an ok button), set the DialogResult property (available to all windows)

```
private void btnDialogOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   this.DialogResult = true;
}
```

Note that setting the DialogResult will automatically cause your popup window to close.

To use your window and get the result...

```
MyPopupWindow popup = new MyPopupWindow ();

if(popup.ShowDialog() == true)
    enteredNumber = popup.anInteger;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. For some reason, my binding isn't working correctly. Isn't it Text=" {Binding anInteger}" ?